# What is the best way to collect data for iphone sqlite db

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, sqlite

I want to build an iphone app with data pre-filled sqlite db. But how to fill data in the beginning comes to be a small problem.

My partner and I may both need to access the db and edit data.

I thought to build a web interface to edit the data, but my host service only provide PHP+MYSQL solution for me, then if I put the data in MYSQL, how to extract it all into a sqlite db?

Any good suggestion for my question? is there any solution for sqlite db remote editing and we can download that sqllite db in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A free and easy solution:
Open a Google Spreadsheet, work on it both, each time you need the result to be inputted into the core data DB just save it as .txt or a .csv and import into the DB.
A plugin for Firefox that you may find useful for the last part: SQLite Manager.
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

i got solution of searching and i done it
this is a code to save sqlite data string save in to txt file at application documents directory

```
-(IBAction)creatTxt{
appDelegate = (evernoteAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *str;

for (int i=0; i<[appDelegate.noteArray count]; i++) {

    nottxtobj = [appDelegate.noteArray objectAtIndex:i];
    str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title=%@\nDiscription=%@",nottxtobj.noteTitle,nottxtobj.noteDisc];
    NSLog(@"data=%@",str);


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filename = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d.txt",nottxtobj.noteID]];
    NSError *error = NULL;
    BOOL written = [str writeToFile:filename atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if (!written)
        NSLog(@"write failed, error=%@", error);
    }



}
```

i hope This code is  useful for you 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about concurrent editing of a SQLite database, but one option you have is to create your database in MySQL then export it as a sql file which you then import into SQLite when you are satisfied with the contents.

There is one obvious problem with this though, the syntax of the two databases differs slightly. As long as you aren't using advanced features of MySQL, the majority of the SQL you export from MySQL, using something like the command line tool `mysqldump` or the export feature in PHPMyAdmin, should work in SQLite.

You would need to prune out the additional data inserted by MySQL for MySQL. Luckily people have wanted to do this before and a [quick google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+to+sqlite) brings up a bunch of promising results.

The SQLite site has some options too: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools

There a bunch of links for software you have to buy, but there is a free shell script about half way down that looks like it might work.